# the process of copying a piece of writing onto another piece of paper by hand

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What verb or phrasal verb do you use to describe the process of copying a piece of writing onto another piece of paper by hand? Can I use the verb *copy*? For example:

> The teacher told me to **copy** the essay onto another piece of paper.

What is the most natural way to comunicate the idea?

Comment: **Copy out:**
to write something again exactly as it has been written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the context makes it clear, your word choice is clear and proper. For example,

> The water damage had rendered the page illegible. So, the teacher told me to copy the essay onto another piece of paper.

However, the more common use of "copy" would be a mechanical copy (scan & print, Xerox copy, etc.). So, if you don't have clear context, a reader might assume that the narrator was being asked to make a mechanical copy.

Lacking any context, I might recommend,

> The teacher told me to copy - by hand - the essay onto another piece of paper.